# How to fix error: list index out of range?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I cant solve this problem. I really need help

here is my code:
https://dpaste.org/PqpYE#L33

here is the error that I am having:

```
File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
percent = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')[a].find('td').find_all(class_ ='styled__PercentContainer-sc-1qtnlbe-0 eeuaGk')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Welcome, please have a look to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your indexing of a starts at 1 but should start at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift `a+=1` to end of `loop`. Python indexing start with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the row and index in tandem by doing `for a, i in enumerate(row):` then you don't need to count up the index manually (you can remove the `a+=1` and the initialization `a=0`).

Comment: Yes, and Its even simpler than that, the index is not needed as the object being operated on is already in i